# Is jQuery an Array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm just getting into jQuery and I am having problems understanding what it is. How can I use array style indexing on a jQuery object but jQuery not be an array? Is this a javascript thing?

```
<ul id="myUL">
<li></li>
<li id="second"></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

var jqueryObject = $("#myUL > li");
alert(jqueryObject[1].attributes.getNamedItem("id").value);

if (jqueryObject instanceof Array) {
    alert('value is Array!');
} else {
    alert('Not an array');//this is what pops up
}
```

Comment: If you have Chrome installed, open up the javascript console on this page and enter:

    var foo = $("div");
    console.log(foo);

Take a look at the returned object. It might help.

Comment: This just gives me an array of divs (didn't know I could do that in Chrome!). I don't see where it indicate how jQuery mimics array indexing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A jQuery collection is an Object with properties numbered like Array indexes (and some other properties and methods), each holding one of the matched elements. It is also given a length property to tell you how many elements the selector matched. See http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

Also, yes, it is partly a JavaScript thing--JS lets you access an object's properties with dot notation or with square-bracket notation.

Comment: Sorry but I'm having problems picturing what you're saying. Are you saying jQuery is like jQuery.0="value", jQuery.1="value"?

Comment: No. `jQuery()` or `$()` is a function which returns a jQuery collection object. This object was built to have some array like properties, but is not an Array. `var myDivCollection = $( 'div' ); //myDivCollection now holds a collection object with all DIV tags from the page in the structure described in the link I put in my answer`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little slow sometimes but I just got it: jqueryObject["2"]="value";//creates a property called 2
alert(jqueryObject[2]); //displays "value"

Comment: Slowness is ok. :) So you have it under control now?

Comment: Well I'm looking at the dev version of jQuery to see if I see numbers being added as properties on the jQuery object and being assigned html elements as values. If I see that then I know I finally got it

Comment: Okay so it's confirmed. In the jQuery code, I saw code like this[0]=element where 'this' is the actual jQuery object. Also learnt that this[0] doesn't mean property at index zero of an array of properties. it actually means property named 0. So if I have var jsObject.four = "value",  jsObject[0] IS NOT equal to "value", jsObject[0] is undefined.

Comment: That they are collections mean that you cannot use array methods that jQuery didn't implement in its collections. Take elements = $(selector1).find(selector2). A console.log will show [Object,Object,Object]. However, you cannot use elements.pop() or elements.shift(). It looks like an  Array, behaves to some extent like an Array, but is not an actual Array type.

Answer (score 5):

Per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery), no:

> The jQuery object itself behaves much
>   like an array; it has a length
>   property and the elements in the
>   object can be accessed by their
>   numeric indices [0] to [length-1].
>   Note that a jQuery object is not
>   actually a Javascript Array object, so
>   it does not have all the methods of a
>   true Array object such as join().

Answer (score 1):

jQuery collection wrapper is an Object in JS sence.

JS objects have operator[] that in general can accept any type as an index.
So these statements are valid:

```
var obj = {};
obj[0] = element1;
obj[1] = element2;
//...
obj[10] = element10;
// and yet
obj[false] = someValue1;
obj[true] = someValue2;
// and obviously 
obj["first"] = 1; // equivalent (but not exact) of obj.first = 1;
obj["second"] = 2;
```

In short object is a key/value map where key can be of any type.

Comment: equivalent (but not exact) of obj.first = 1; ? How so?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. But if you wanna use JS Array methods, like `.join()` after a `$(...).map(...)` call, you can use the `$.makeArray` that converts a jQuery collection to a true JS Array:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/