# How to use += operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, operators

Since I started using JQuery ive always wondering how does this operator work in JQuery
Example:

```
for(var i = 0;i<=4;i++)
{
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerText += i;//<- works as expected
}

//results will be 0,1,2,3,4
```

but if i use JQuery instead i dont know how to do it

```
for(var i = 0;i<=4;i++)
{
$("mydiv").text(+i)//<- NO!
$("mydiv").text+(i)//<- NO!
$("mydiv").+text(i)//<- JAJA COME ON!
$("mydiv").text(i)+//<- I guess that was stupid


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible like this. Unlike `innerText`, `text()` is a method, not a property.

Try:

```
$("mydiv").text($("mydiv").text() + i);
```

Or if you'd rather not make 2 references to `$("mydiv")` you can do:

```
$("mydiv").text(function(i,v){
   return v + i; 
});
```

Comment: That's why I sometimes don't like JQuery :(

Comment: That's not the jQuery way.

Comment: @Bergi Not very clear, but you're right, there is a cleaner method. I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Stasel This shouldn't be a reason to not like jQuery. Unlike InnerText, `text()` is not a property, its a method.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to work with jQuery here. Use the `text` method to extract the value, and then call it again to set the new value:

```
for(var i = 0;i<=4;i++)
{
    var mydiv = $("mydiv"),
        t = mydiv.text();
    mydiv.text(t + i);
}
```

Comment: Do not call the same selector expression twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use such shorcuts for jQuery methods, it only works for [native assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators). For [jQuery `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2), use a callback:

```
$("#mydiv").text(function(index, oldtext) {
    return oldtext + i;
});
```

This callback thing works for all jQuery property "assignments", be it `.html`, [`.val`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10487850/1048572), `.prop`, `.attr`, `.css`, or `.text`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not a programming language but a library built upon javascript, so, the rules are exactly the same as those you have to follow using javascript, and javascript has not been designed to understand these kinds of structures.

---

### Edit

Of course I mean `o.m(+1)` does not increment `o.p` while `o.p++` and `o.p+=1` does :

```
var o = {};
o.p = 1;
o.m = function () { return this.p; };
o.m(+1); // o.p equals 1
o.p++;   // o.p equals 2
o.p+=1;  // o.p equals 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers point out, jQuery is just a framework and is subject to same syntactic rules as any JavaScript code.

While I see the advantage of passing in a `function` to `.text()`, I don't think it's a general purpose approach to solve your real problem : how to concatenate text when you use a function instead of a variable.

I'd favor the usage of `Array.join()` for efficient concatenation:

```
var textParts = [ $("mydiv").text() ];
for(var i = 0;i<=4;i++)
{
    textParts[textParts.length] = i;
}
$("mydiv").text(textParts.join(',')) // result: '...,1,2,3,4'
```

If you prefer the function approach over a loop, you could also use `Array.map()`.

AFAIK DOM functions are rather slow so it's more effective to do the concatenation **first** and **then** set the `div` node value.