# How do you cache a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that referencing `$('#Counter')` over and over is a bad idea because you are "jumping into the DOM each time".

But is this any better?

```
Counter = $('#Counter');
```

And then inside the loop:

```
Counter.val()++
```

**Edit:**

Correction to the snippet above, which should be:

```
Counter.val(Counter.val()+1);
```

Or is that doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, it is better. You're querying the DOM once vs. *N* times.

Comment: It's a bit more efficient to use a variable if you plan on re-using it more than once. jQuery will cache selectors and results, by using the variable you bypass the need for that extra code.

Comment: Yeah, but the variable is just pointing to the DOM.

Comment: That looks like a good improvment and an example of how to cache and element from the DOM... Throw a `var` in front of `Counter` and we'll give you a gold star.

Comment: `Counter.val()++` will be a runtime error - you can't assign to the result of calling this function. Did you want `Counter.val()+1`?

Comment: done.  However, I'm thinking of putting any "DOM cache" variables into the global scope.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Ok... If that's what you **really** want to do, no need for var. Maybe you should cache your DOM elements inside of a single object that is global (rather than polluting the global scope)?  As that owl used to say: "_Give a hoot, don't pollute!_" ;-)

Comment: possibly related to [jquery .val() += idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487850/jquery-val-idiom)

Comment: @Bergi I don't think that's the point at all. The OP was just demonstrating what they were doing inside the loop. This is no duplicate. The question's about caching, not specifically what for. Your suggestion was clearly correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the case you described, it is preferrable to save jQuery object in a variable before entering the iteration statement, where you repeatedly use this object. It will prevent of traversing the DOM tree at each iteration. Besides it can be insensible for searching by ID, but querying by class name or using compound selectors may sufficiently decrease the performance.

```
var $Counter = $("#Counter");
for (...) {
    $Counter.val(function(i, val) { return +val + 1; });
    ...
}
```

Pay attention to using function as argument of `val()` which is more reasonable in this case.