# jQuery array comparison with ==?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have two jQuery arrays `initialList` and `newList`.

I first compare them like so:

```
initialList == newList
```

This returns `false`.

Then I compare element by element:

```
$.each(initialList, function(idx, element){ console.log(element == newList[idx] )});
```

Every comparison is `true`.

So if all elements are identical why return false in the first comparison?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229197/how-to-know-if-two-arrays-have-the-same-values last ans: When you compare those two arrays, you're comparing the objects that represent the arrays, not the contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking if they're *equivilent* (all items the same), whereas the `==` operator is checking if they are *the same thing* (references to the same object). They're not, so `==` returns false.

If you're asking *philosophically* why `==` doesn't evaluate the operands and tell you if for all intents and purposes they're 'the same', you can read more about equivalence verses equality [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3D%3D#Equality) (Object identity vs. Content equality).

Answer (score 2):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pEzAW/

Now when you use `==` operator you are trying to compare one object with another object not its state, where as in the loop version you are comparing the elements.

You can do a way simpler version like this: to check the length as well see this: http://jsfiddle.net/ASnYu/1/

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,2,3]

alert(arr1 == arr2)


if ($(arr1).not(arr2).length == 0 && $(arr2).not(arr1).length == 0 && arr1.length == arr2.length)
    alert("Two arrays are Identical");​
```

**If order is important for *identity* do this** using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ValueOf

http://jsfiddle.net/Putjc/

**code**

```
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [2, 1, 3]

if ($(arr1).not(arr2).length == 0 && $(arr2).not(arr1).length == 0 && arr1.length == arr2.length && arr1.valueOf().toString() == arr2.valueOf().toString()) 
         alert("Two arrays are Identical"); 
else alert("two arrays are **not** identical");​
```

Random interesting read: [Is jQuery an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827191/is-jquery-an-array)

Rest hope it fits the cause!

Comment: `[1,2,3]` and `[1,1,2,3]`, are they Identical?

Comment: @xdazz Thank bruv `:)` *fixed* http://jsfiddle.net/ASnYu/1/ and working http://jsfiddle.net/ASnYu

Comment: `[1,2,3]` and `[2,1,3]`, are they identical?

Comment: @DavidHedlund +d, thanks for the comment bruver :)) I reckon order is different but both contain the same element, I will see how I can squeeze in the order check as well :),

Comment: @DavidHedlund **Enhanced Fixed**  for the order as well `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/Putjc/ Thanks man!